# How to group array of string using split?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, group-by

Hi I have an array of string

`["Facebook_18_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_17_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_16_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_15_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_14_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_13_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_18_2014/03/17_1", "Facebook_17_2014/03/17_1", "Facebook_16_2014/03/17_1", "Facebook_15_2014/03/17_1", "Facebook_14_2014/03/17_1", "Facebook_13_2014/03/17_1", "Facebook_18_2015/03/17_1", "Facebook_17_2015/03/17_1", "Facebook_16_2015/03/17_1", "Facebook_15_2015/03/17_1", "Facebook_14_2015/03/17_1", "Facebook_13_2015/03/17_1","Facebook_18_2013/04/12_1", "Facebook_17_2013/05/11_1", "Facebook_16_2013/05/01_1", "Facebook_15_2013/04/03_1", "Facebook_14_2013/06/03_1", "Facebook_13_2013/06/15_1"]`

from this array i want to group the string with date,year,month.

Expected output

`{"2013/03"=>["Facebook_18_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_17_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_16_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_15_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_14_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_13_2013/03/17_1"],"2013/04"=>["Facebook_18_2013/04/17_1", "Facebook_17_2013/04/17_1", "Facebook_16_2013/04/17_1", "Facebook_15_2013/04/17_1", "Facebook_14_2013/04/17_1", "Facebook_13_2013/04/17_1"], "2014/03"=>["Facebook_18_2014/03/17_1", "Facebook_17_2014/03/17_1", "Facebook_16_2014/03/17_1", "Facebook_15_2014/03/17_1", "Facebook_14_2014/03/17_1", "Facebook_13_2014/03/17_1"], "2015/03"=>["Facebook_18_2015/03/17_1", "Facebook_17_2015/03/17_1", "Facebook_16_2015/03/17_1", "Facebook_15_2015/03/17_1", "Facebook_14_2015/03/17_1", "Facebook_13_2015/03/17_1"]}`

i used the following ruby code to group based on year

```
a.flatten.uniq.group_by{|x| x.split("_")[3].split("/")[0]}
```

so how can i do it for year with moth (ex: 2013/04)?

Comment: Thanks i got it using flatten.uniq.group_by{|x| x.split("_")[3][0..6]}

Comment: Please [answer your own question :)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since only year, /, and month are concerned here and `\d` is a bit expensive, the solution could also be written like this:

```
a = [
      "Facebook_18_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_17_2013/03/17_1", 
      "Facebook_16_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_15_2013/03/17_1", 
      "Facebook_14_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_13_2013/03/17_1", 
      "Facebook_18_2014/03/17_1", "Facebook_17_2014/03/17_1", 
      "Facebook_16_2014/03/17_1", "Facebook_15_2014/03/17_1", 
      "Facebook_14_2014/03/17_1", "Facebook_13_2014/03/17_1", 
      "Facebook_18_2015/03/17_1", "Facebook_17_2015/03/17_1", 
      "Facebook_16_2015/03/17_1", "Facebook_15_2015/03/17_1", 
      "Facebook_14_2015/03/17_1", "Facebook_13_2015/03/17_1", 
      "Facebook_18_2013/04/12_1", "Facebook_17_2013/05/11_1", 
      "Facebook_16_2013/05/01_1", "Facebook_15_2013/04/03_1", 
      "Facebook_14_2013/06/03_1", "Facebook_13_2013/06/15_1"
    ]

a.group_by { |s| s[/([0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2})/,1] }

#{
#  "2013/03"=>["Facebook_18_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_17_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_16_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_15_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_14_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_13_2013/03/17_1"], 
#  "2014/03"=>["Facebook_18_2014/03/17_1", "Facebook_17_2014/03/17_1", "Facebook_16_2014/03/17_1", "Facebook_15_2014/03/17_1", "Facebook_14_2014/03/17_1", "Facebook_13_2014/03/17_1"], 
#  "2015/03"=>["Facebook_18_2015/03/17_1", "Facebook_17_2015/03/17_1", "Facebook_16_2015/03/17_1", "Facebook_15_2015/03/17_1", "Facebook_14_2015/03/17_1", "Facebook_13_2015/03/17_1"], 
#  "2013/04"=>["Facebook_18_2013/04/12_1", "Facebook_15_2013/04/03_1"], 
#  "2013/05"=>["Facebook_17_2013/05/11_1", "Facebook_16_2013/05/01_1"], 
#  "2013/06"=>["Facebook_14_2013/06/03_1", "Facebook_13_2013/06/15_1"]
#}
```

And this is a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

Just do as below :

```
a = [
      "Facebook_18_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_17_2013/03/17_1", 
      "Facebook_16_2013/03/17_1","Facebook_15_2013/03/17_1", 
      "Facebook_14_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_13_2013/03/17_1", 
      "Facebook_18_2014/03/17_1", "Facebook_17_2014/03/17_1", 
      "Facebook_16_2014/03/17_1" 
    ]

a.group_by { |s| s[/Facebook_\d+_(\d+\/\d+)\/\d+_\d+/,1] }

# => {"2013/03"=>["Facebook_18_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_17_2013/03/17_1", 
# "Facebook_16_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_15_2013/03/17_1", 
# "Facebook_14_2013/03/17_1", "Facebook_13_2013/03/17_1"], 
# "2014/03"=>["Facebook_18_2014/03/17_1", "Facebook_17_2014/03/17_1"
# , "Facebook_16_2014/03/17_1"]}
```